# Php Script to delete and create files and folder using .bat not working when run using Windows Scheduler

Tags: windows, directory, scheduler, delete-file

I was trying create folder and save images using php in loop, it is running fine from **.bat** file manually.

**It is creating all respective folders and image files, but when run using windows scheduler its is not creating folders.**

The job is successfully completed when checked the Scheduler status.

Also I ran a delete to clean up old folders and images this also works fine if I ran the .bat file manually but not deleting any folder when run through scheduler.

**The below is the .bat file code.**

**Am I missing some permission issue in Scheduler that prevent me from creating folder and images?**

```
c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:\xampp\htdocs\retrieve_image.php
```

This is the bat file code I have created to run the *.php file

```
while ($row = $db->fetch_array($r2)) {

        $sysid = $row[ml_num];
        $prop_id = $row[property_id];


        $n = 1;
        $dir = 'photos/' . $sysid;
        if (!is_dir($dir)) mkdir($dir); 

        $photos = $rets->GetObject('Property', 'Photo', $sysid);            
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            $loc = $dir . "/" . $n . ".jpg";
            file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $n . '.jpg', $photo['Data']);

            if (imagecreatefromjpeg($loc) !== false) {
                echo $loc . "<br/>";
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO property_images(property_id, pimg_name,status) values('$prop_id','$loc',1)";

                $r3 = $db->query($sql2);
            }
            else
            {
                $status = unlink($loc);
            }
            $n++;

        }

        $i++;
    }
```

This is the php code to retrieve image and create a new folder and put images in while loop. It is working fine when I ran .bat file manually.

***Please help me in running this action through windows scheduler.***

Comment: Start in path corrected the issue.

Start in (optional):c:\xampp\htdocs\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the task properties --> Action tab --> Edit --> Fill up as below:

**Start in (optional):** Put the full path to your batch script location

eg: `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

Then Click OK

It works for me. Good Luck!